# Editar/Atualizar - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Boa tarde! Estou tentando editar de "João Torres" para "João Torres Moreira", porém aparece a mensagem erro abaixo.

> A instrução de atualização, inserção ou exclusão de repositório afetou
>   um número inesperado de linhas (0). As entidades podem ter sido
>   modificadas ou excluídas após o carregamento. Atualize as entradas do
>   ObjectStateManager.

Segue a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código MedicosController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CadeMeuMedico.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;

namespace CadeMeuMedico.Controllers
{
    public class MedicosController : Controller
    {
        private CadeMeuMedicoBDEntities db = new CadeMeuMedicoBDEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Medicos/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var medicos = db.Medicos.Include(m => m.Cidades).Include(m => m.Especialidades).ToList();
            return View(medicos);
        }

        public ActionResult Adicionar()
        {
            ViewBag.IDCidade = new SelectList(db.Cidades, "IDCidade", "Nome");
            ViewBag.IDEspecialidade = new SelectList(db.Especialidades, "IDEspecialidade", "Nome");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Adicionar(Medicos medicos)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Medicos.Add(medicos);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.IDCidade = new SelectList(db.Cidades, "IDCidade", "Nome", medicos.IDCidade);
            ViewBag.IDEspecialidade = new SelectList(db.Especialidades, "IDEspecialidade", "Nome", medicos.IDEspecialidade);
            return View(medicos);

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Editar(long id)
        {
            Medicos medicos = db.Medicos.Find(id);
            ViewBag.IDCidade = new SelectList(db.Cidades, "IDCidade", "Nome", medicos.IDCidade);
            ViewBag.IDEspecialidade = new SelectList(db.Especialidades, "IDEspecialidade", "Nome", medicos.IDEspecialidade);
            return View(medicos);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Editar(Medicos medicos)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(medicos).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.IDCidade = new SelectList(db.Cidades, "IDCidade", "Nome", medicos.IDCidade);
            ViewBag.IDEspecialidade = new SelectList(db.Especialidades, "IDEspecialidade", "Nome", medicos.IDEspecialidade);
            return View(medicos);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Excluir(long id)
        {
            try
            {
                Medicos medicos = db.Medicos.Find(id);
                db.Medicos.Remove(medicos);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Boolean.TrueString;
            }
            catch
            {
                return Boolean.FalseString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: porque você está forçando o `EntityState.Modified;` o ideal seria você fazer uma consulta através do "id", alterar os atributos que achar necessário e aí executar o `SaveChanges()`. O parâmetro de entrada do método editar não faz parte do seu contexto, é a apenas a deserialização do post recebido pela view.

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas possibilidades para este erro estar acontecendo...

1ª - O E.F não está identificando que existe alteração na sua entidade, porque pode ser que ela não exista de fato no banco.

2ª - Caso a primeira possibilidade seja descartada, você pode primeiro consultar a entidade, colocando-a no contexto do E.F, alterar o que vier de sua `view` e na sequencia atualizar o objeto.

Eliminando essas duas possibilidades, acredito que resolva o problema. Uma abordagem que também pode usar afim de testes é, a seguinte:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Db.Entry(medico).State = medico.MedicoId == null ? 
    EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Caso não exista um MedicoId o objeto recebe o *Status* `added` que faz com que o contexto do E.F interprete que está adicionando esta entidade, caso não aí sim ela recebe o *Status* `Modified`.

Através do Debug você também pode verificar se a entidade está chegando para a atuaização preenchida corretamente. Caso isso não resolva, poste também, como sua entidade está chegando, acrescentando mais detalhes do problema fica mais fácil chegar a uma resolução.